How to deal with special characters in a dataframe
I have a csv file where I have some columns of type string where the special characters have strange crackers or letters. For example, for españa, I have espa¿a. For algodón, I have algod¿on. There is any effective ideas that I could use to fix this words with special characters. I'm using python and pyspark.
It is not possible to do a replace the bad caracter for the good one because there are different bad character for the ñ and also can be the same bad caracter to the ñ or to ó.

This question is similar to: How to parse CSV file with UTF-8 encoding?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You might be reading the file using the wrong encoding. If the CSV file that you are trying to read was encoded in ISO-8859-1 or Latin-1, but you're trying to read it as UTF-8, this could cause issues.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("FixSpecialChars").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("your_file.csv", header=True, encoding="ISO-8859-1") #ISO-8859-1 or Latin-1

df.show()

